# Error inside threads in IPB

Tags: ipb

Getting this error when I try to view a thread:
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/forum/public_html/hooks/contentRatingsPost_e5cf98fbd73a08ec82d714032b259e78.php on line 133*

Line 133:
*uasort($data['rating_totals'], function($a, $b) { if(count($b)==count($a)){return 0;} return (count($b) < count($a)) ? -1 : 1; });*

Answer (score 0):

Report it to the author of that hook, or ask your host to upgrade your PHP version, as the one you have now does not allow the use of [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).